# Display user information from react Jhipster App

Tags: reactjs, frontend, jhipster

I'm using Jhipster with react.
I'm trying to get and display user information (name for example) in my react header.
Example :

- user : admin
- password : *******

display

hello admin in header

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some code sample of what you're trying to do, so other users can have a better idea of the issue you're dealing with. Show what you've already done and where you're stuck.

Comment: You might wanna try https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-react .